# Check if an Android device has a certain hardware button in code

Tags: java, android, button, hardware

I need to check if a certain android device has a hardware button in code. For example only some phones have the search button. 
So how do I check if a device has a hardware button(Search, camera, d-pad, etc) or not?

Comment: duplicated from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269891/check-if-android-device-has-search-hardware-button

Comment: Well I was asking a general way to check hardware buttons, they was just asking for the search button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`PackageManager.hasSystemFeature()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29).
Example:

```
boolean hasCamera = 
        getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

You can also get some of the features which are not testable by the `PackageManager` via the [`Configuration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html), e.g. the DPAD.

```
Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();
if(c.navigation == Configuration.NAVIGATION_DPAD)
      hasDpad = true;
```

The only exception is the search button. There was a question here a few days ago, asking basically the same. I don't remember any answer and I don't know a way to detect the search button, since it's not in the list of features. *(Edit: There you go, possible duplicate thread is the one i mentioned here)*

Comment: Awesome. Though shame about the search button, I'll tick this and just watch the other thread.

Comment: I don't think this answer can be accepted, this will only check if there is a camera installed on the device and NOT if there is a camera hardware button installed. AFAIK there is no such feature in the SDK.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a good clean way of checking if the Hardware "Menu" button is present:

```
ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481965
See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey()

Comment: Good to know . For anyone who uses it , do note that it requires API14 and above .

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is over a year old, but with it still showing up in Google searches (on the first page). I figured, I would post a slight update or suggestion with what I am using in-case someone like me is searching for the same thing.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
           if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) { 
               Toast.makeText(this,"VOL Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return true;
           } else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH){
               Toast.makeText(this,"search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return false;
           }else{
               Toast.makeText(this,"Vol Up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return true;
               //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
           }
    }
```

I have placed out side the onCreate().. This works fine on my Thunderbolt (Rooted running MikMik GingerGrits)

Comment: Originally, I needed to check if the device had a hardware button before the app is shown. This will only work once that hardware button is pressed. But thanks for sharing.

Comment: Ya this is a working solution. Ya I checked it with HTC ADR6300. This is the best way to detect a hardware search button stroke.

Answer (score 0):

can use these APIs to check to see if the device has a specific physical key that will send a specific keycode when pressed.

- [KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKeys(int[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap#deviceHasKeys(int%5B%5D))
- [KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap#deviceHasKey(int))
- [InputDevice.hasKeys(int[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice#hasKeys(int%5B%5D))

```kotlin
private fun logDeviceKeyCapabilities() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Build.MODEL: ${Build.MODEL}")
    val deviceHasKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(300)
    Log.i(TAG, "deviceHasKey(300): $deviceHasKey")
    InputDevice.getDeviceIds().toList()
        .map { id -> id to InputDevice.getDevice(id) }
        .mapNotNull { (id, device) -> device?.let { id to device } }
        .forEach { (id, device) -> logInputDeviceInfo(id, device) }
}

private fun logInputDeviceInfo(id: Int, device: InputDevice) {
    Log.i(TAG,"InputDevice($id).name: ${device.name}")
    Log.i(TAG,"InputDevice($id).descriptor: ${device.descriptor}")
    Log.i(TAG,"InputDevice($id).productId: ${device.productId}")
    Log.i(TAG,"InputDevice($id).vendorId: ${device.vendorId}")
    Log.i(TAG,"InputDevice($id).device.hasKeys(300): ${device.hasKeys(300).toList()}")
    Log.i(TAG,"InputDevice($id).device.hasKeys(Int.MAX_VALUE): ${device.hasKeys(Int.MAX_VALUE).toList()}")
    Log.i(TAG,"InputDevice($id).device.hasKeys(Int.MIN_VALUE): ${device.hasKeys(Int.MIN_VALUE).toList()}")
    Log.i(TAG,"InputDevice($id).device.hasKeys(0): ${device.hasKeys(0).toList()}")
    Log.i(TAG,"InputDevice($id).device.hasKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK): ${device.hasKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK).toList()}")
}
```