# How to determine menu support is available or not in android

Tags: android, menu

My app is using device's menu option for navigate to other pages.
Problem which I see now, with latest Nexus 7, there is no hardware menu option is available so I put a button to menu for user access.
But now problem is I'm unable to determine that on which devices, menu option is already available so it's showing two menus 1. My button 2. Device's supported menu option.
I would like show only one, could any one help me on it?

Comment: This has been and answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044907/android-programmatically-detect-if-device-has-hardware-menu-button

Answer (score 0):

Menu option is available from (Android 3.0)api 11 and above. You don't need to use your own button for that check this developer [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

If you want show on ur own button remove `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method and use `openOptionsMenu()` and call it onClick of ur button.

Comment: No it's not true, menu option for is not present in Nexus 7, it's working on all other devices, but in nexus 7, no menu options is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey()
```