# Android : check wether action button (home,back, etc.. ) is inside the screen or not?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

i would like to explain in more detail,

some of android device have action button like this,
[image]

while some of device have like,

[image]

in first case all action button is outside the screen while in second case action button is given bottom of screen(inside the screen)... how can i detect that where the action button is present? i have no idea about it..!!

Comment: Don't forget some devices have buttons not on the screen at all (Samsung devices).

Comment: @GabeSechan That's what he is showing with his first picture

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044907/android-programmatically-detect-if-device-has-hardware-menu-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092431/check-for-navigation-bar), but not 100% guarantee to work for all device, some device like HTC, LAVA etc not working with that. Also minApi required 13+ for that...!!

Answer (score 1):

Check the official Android docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap.html#deviceHasKey%28int%29

The method deviceHasKey will solve your problem. (Use Keycodes KEYCODE_MENU, KEYCODE_HOME, KEYCODE_BACK). 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by doing the following check in your `onCreate()`:

for api 14 and up

```
boolean PermanentMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(this).hasPermanentMenuKey(); // true if physical, false if virtual
```

for lower api:

```
boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
boolean hasHomeKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);

if (hasBackKey && hasHomeKey) {
    // no navigation bar, unless it is enabled in the settings
} else {
    // 99% sure there's a navigation bar
}
```

Comment: check [Check for navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092431/check-for-navigation-bar) and [KeyCharacterMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyCharacterMap.html#deviceHasKey(int))

Comment: thnxx Strider for your ans.!

Answer (score 0):

You may get your answer here.
[Check for navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092431/check-for-navigation-bar)

p.s. The formal name of the bar is "Navigation Bar"
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html