# How to target devices with and without soft navigation keys (ie: Nexus 5, Galaxy S4)?

Tags: android, layout, styles, screen-size, softkeys

I was looking everywhere for an answer with no success. I am using the values-xxhdpi folder to set my app's layout dimensions for the nexus 5, but as I switch to the galaxy S4 emulator (same resolution but without soft navigation keys) the layout is not ok any more.

Is there a way to target devices having the same resolution with and without the soft navigation at the bottom of the screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
ViewConfiguration.hasPermanentMenuKey()
```

**NOTE**
This only works for SDK >= 14

**EDITED:**

```
boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
boolean hasHomeKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);

if (hasBackKey && hasHomeKey) {
    // no navigation bar, unless it is enabled in the settings
} else {
    // 99% sure there's a navigation bar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether a device has a hardware menu key or not (the method you can use to achieve that, is described for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044907/android-programmatically-detect-if-device-has-hardware-menu-button)) and apply a different set of resources yourself.

There's no way to do that "automatically" for example by forcing an app to use a different `drawable` folder.