# Android Menu Overflow

Tags: java, android, menu

My Problem is that in some cases the overflow menu dosent work on some phones. First i thought it is the android version and designed 2 different menu xml.
But a Samsung Mini S4 with 4.2.2 doesnt show the overflow and Samsung S5 with 4.2.2 shows the overflow menu.
It seem maybe something to be with the hardware buttons, i dont figure it out.

Can anyone help me how to detect when the menu overflow is shown? 
I use following: Com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3

Thanks Malte

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the hardware menu button. So on devices that have the hardware menu button, the overflow menu will not display since the user can use the hardware button (it reduces redundancy). However, IMO it also reduces usability since most users do not think to hit that button (at the least, they do not in my apps).

So you can detect the hardware button: [Android: Programmatically detect if device has hardware menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044907/android-programmatically-detect-if-device-has-hardware-menu-button)

And then display a menu item that looks like the "***" menu button and have it activate the menu if you like.