# Android Physical/Capacitive Navigation Buttons

Tags: java, android, button, navigation

how to check On-Screen or Physical/Capacitive Navigation Buttons on device[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey()`

only available for API level 14+

more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey%28%29) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9481965/5222007)

the best answer that helped will be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16608481/5222007)

```
boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

if(!hasMenuKey && !hasBackKey) {

}
```

Comment: HI @saur as above solution is working fine in Nexus , samsung  devices but not working in Moto x play as welll Micro max device so is there any general solution ?

Comment: @Arpan24x7 i have tested the code in moto e(1st gen)(L) and moto g(3rd gen)(M) for softkeyboard and redmi 1s(J) , redmi prime(K) as well as micromax a106(L) for hard keyboard and is working fine for me......is it specific to moto x play? which micromax device is it?

Comment: Here i found bug in two device which i have,

1) Moto X play 
2) Micromax Canvas Express 2