# How can I determine if an android device has physical or virtual navigation keys using Ionic v2?

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2

I'm building an app using ionic v2 and I find myself having to determine whether or not the device has physical or virtual navigation keys?

Comment: i guess there's no particular cordova plugin for this. All you can do is to write a native code and call it. Refer this answer which can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9481965/1848109 Read the comments section in this answer

Comment: Thanks but it turns out I don't need it @Nirus I just used a plugin that gets me the actual screen resolution and I make it work. I was trying to set an offset for a banner ad.