# How to Detect if Android Device has no physical or on-screen buttons?

Tags: android, react-native, button, detection

Many Android Phones Like Google Pixel 3 and Xiaomi Mi Mix 2 etc, Does not have any on-screen or physical navigation buttons, they work with gestures. In React-Native, this is a huge problem, because if I detect the height of the screen, On modern devices, this leaves some empty screen from the bottom.

I've tried this solution, it works fine with devices with either hardware or on-screen buttons, but returns null for modern devices with no buttons.
[Determine whether hardware buttons are drawn on screen in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676208/determine-whether-hardware-buttons-are-drawn-on-screen-in-react-native#)

My current RN version: 0.59.5

Image:
[This is the UI Screenshot From MI MIX 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoXtq.png)

Comment: ask the user themselves to clarify it through a dialog

Answer (score 4):

You can compare the difference between the device and the window (usable) height:

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

let deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
let windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
let bottomNavBarHeight = deviceHeight - windowHeight;
if (bottomNavBarHeight > 0) {
    // onscreen navbar
} else {
    // not onscreen navbar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use `react-native-device-info` to gather mobile device model and other details, that you could filter out those modern mobile devices which doesn't support on-screen or hardware back button and deal with those mobile devices with your custom snippet.

I suppose you are using Flexbox and [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) from React Native Api to handle your app responsivness.

Also, it would be better if you could share the UI screenshot and the codebase you have used thus far.

Comment: But isn't using `react-native-device-info` a long shot, I mean, there are many phones being launched that are bazel-less with no on-screen or without hardware button, do we manage all of them through this library? Because the closer you can get with this library is to check for the notch, not for the buttons.
Thank you for the effort though, really appreciate it. 
If you could find any concrete answer, do share it with here me or in FB Developer Circle.

Comment: Updated the Question with Screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

I belive i have found a solution.

```
if((screenHeigth-windowHeigth)-StatusBar.currentHeight > 0) {
    // don't have digital on-screen buttons 
  } else {
    // have digital on-screen buttons 
  }
```