# Is it possible to detect Android virtual buttons programmatically?

Tags: android, button, virtual

Android seems to be cutting off the bottom 100px on devices that have virtual / on screen buttons. Is it possible to detect if the current phone / tablet is using on screen buttons so that I can account for the missing space? If so, is it possible to get the height of the buttons as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the device has a permanent (hardware) menu button by using [`hasPermanentMenuKey()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey()). It can be used as following:

```
boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
```

Notice that this technique will work only on APIs 14+ (ICS, JB). No device pre-API-11 has menu buttons, so that leaves only APIs 11-13 without a check; keep in mind that these 3 API levels have only [2.3% of the Android population](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) currently.

Alternately (though not reliably), you could try searching for a D-Pad:

```
boolean hasDpad = getResources().getConfiguration().naviation == Configuration.NAVIGATION_DPAD;
```

There is no way to check for a hardware search button (and I would assume home/back as well), as seen [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/zzErTdL9tEA%5B1-25%5D). (Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269891/check-if-android-device-has-search-hardware-button); this thread proposes an alternative method, though I'm not sure it will work in your case.)

I will mention two things: The virtual buttons should NEVER be covering your content. They do subtract from the height of the device window (as fetched by the display's metrics), but they will never hinder your layout if you are using `match_parent` as a height. Second, there is no way to fetch the exact height of the virtual button bar; it may change between builds. There is also no native way in the Android API to fetch the "available" screen space (the area that is not covered by the bar at the bottom).

**So**, here is what I will suggest:

- Forget checking for hardware buttons. You should only be concerned with how much space you have, not how much you are losing (or why you are losing it).
- Make a [custom layout type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) (extending `ViewGroup` or `LinearLayout` or something).
- Wrap your existing layout in this layout.
- You can now override [`onLayout()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)) or [`onMeasure()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)), and get your layout's *exact* height from this. (You may want to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423082/authorative-way-to-override-onmeasure) for reference.)

Comment: Thanks! There doesn't seem to be anything I can do then. However, at least on the Nexus 7, the virtual buttons ARE covering my content, despite setting match_parent. The quickest test I could find is to fill a ScrollView with match_parent. The thin blue line that signifies you can't scroll further is cut off on the edge with buttons. (In my case, there's a draggable handle about the same height that disappears off the screen if I don't account for it). Hopefully I'm wrong, though, since I haven't tested without the handle logic. If it's something I did wrong, that's much easier to fix.

Comment: That's very odd; I don't have that issue on my Galaxy Nexus. Sadly I don't have a Nexus 7 to confirm it. Sorry I couldn't be more help!

Comment: PADDING! Oh god. Padding is what caused my issues. I... feel embarrassed now. But thank god it was my fault.

Comment: Agreed! Glad you got it fixed now! :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, the virtual buttons on the bottom are only in android versions 3.0 (Honeycomb) and above. 
As for the height issue, I've never really looked into it.

Comment: They still make phones with hardware buttons, though, so I can't assume all 3.0+ devices will have virtual buttons.

Comment: Kindle Fire has a virtual button bar and runs gingerbread (2.3)